# Php Carbon use Carbon\Carbon

Tags: php, namespaces, php-carbon

I am trying a way to avoid putting  `use Carbon\Carbon;` in every php file I use Carbon. Is there a way to use Carbon\Carbon everywhere in one line?

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;
echo Carbon::now();
```

Comment: Do you use Laravel in that particular case?

Comment: No I don't use Laravel but I'm currious about how Larabel is using Carbon.

Answer (score 3):

Importing a class with use only works in the current file.  If you want to access Carbon from the root namespace, you can always create a class alias.

```
class_alias(\Carbon\Carbon::class, 'Carbon');
```

As long as you have this in a file that is included, you'll be able to use `Carbon` instead of `\Carbon\Carbon` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a helper function, something like this :

`src/helpers.php` :

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('carbon')) {
     function carbon(): \Carbon\Carbon 
     {
         return \Carbon\Carbon::now();
     }
}
```

make sure to add the helper functions file to composer autoload :

`composer.json` :

```
...
"autoload": {
     "files": [
         "src/helpers.php"
     ]
}
...
```

later in your code you can use it as :

```
<?php

$date = carbon();
```